# Parse a substring out of string, allocate memory accordingly

Tags: c, strings, linux

I have written the following code in order to:

1. Find begin and end of FTP user and password from a given URL (`ftp://[user[:password]@]host[:port]/url-path`)
2. Allocate memory to hold this string
3. Copy the sub-string into the allocated memory

Here is the code for your review:

```
static char * swd_parseUsrPass(void)
{
    char *usr_pass = NULL;
    char *url_str = NULL;
    char *beginIndx = NULL;
    char *endIndx = NULL;
    int str_len = 0;

    url_str = getURLaddr();

    /* Find begin and end indexs */
    beginIndx = url_str + strlen(FTP_PREFIX);
    endIndx = strchr(beginIndx, '@');

    if ((endIndx == NULL) || endIndx <= beginIndx) {
        printf("Could not locate user and password in URL\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    str_len = endIndx - beginIndx;

    /* Allocate maximum possible string */
    usr_pass = malloc((sizeof(char) * str_len) + 1);
    if (usr_pass == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocated memory!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Copy user and password to new string */
    strncpy(usr_pass, beginIndx, str_len);
    *(endIndx + 1) = '\0';

    return usr_pass;
}
```

Comment: Though not common. The `@` character can appear in the `url-path`

Comment: Also if this was going to go into real code. You have to remember that on the web URL don't always follow spec (as a writer of a web crawler I can testify to the number of badly written URLS). So the '/' marking the `url-path` may not be there so you have to check for all the common mistakes.  `?` , `&` , `#` , `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A 0-ary function (`swd_parseUsrPass`) calling another 0-ary function (`swd_getURLaddr`) hints that there are global variables lurking around. Using globals is not recommended; if they are unavoidable, at least limit their visibility. Consider `char swd_parseUsrPass(char * url_addr)`, and let the caller provide the argument.
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.
- `*(endIndx + 1) = '\0'` modifies the source string, while `usr_pass` remains not terminated. I presume you meant

  ```
  usr_pass[str_len] = '\0';
  ```

Comment: Thank you @vnp. I'm actually not using global variables, but I do use static variables (defined only in this C file content) - do you see any problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all points made by vnp, except I'd suggest `swd_parseUsrPass(const char *url_addr)` as the prototype, and I'd add:

- all your pointers except `usr_pass` should be `const char *` as you do not intend to modify the string they point to. This would have help you noticing the `*(endIndx + 1) = '\0'` issue pointed out by vnp.
- the test `endIndx <= beginIndx` seems redundant to me
- I'm not a big fan of `Indx` in the name: these are pointers, indexes would be integers (not a big fan of mixing underscores and camelCase either, but that's more an issue of taste)